# VBA Excel: "yyyy" type string into date

Tags: excel, vba

Noob question:

how do I transform a "yyyy" string into a date?

My goal is to do the following

```
If "yyyy" < VBA.Date then
...
End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"yyyy" is a string. If you want to get todays date as a string you can use:

```
Format(Date, "yyyy")
```

You can use `CDate()` to convert strings to dates.

```
CDate("1/1/2013")
```

If you are just trying to compare the year you could do something like this:

```
If CInt("2012") < Format(Date, "yyyy") Then
    Debug.Print True
End If
```